# Android application with social media VerifyError

Tags: android

I am developing an android application using different social media APIs including Facebook , Twitter , LinkedIn. I am trying to manage these three accounts from a single app. I have included twitter and LinkedIn and Facebook APIs as .jar files and also used Facebook S.D.K with reference . but when I run the app in the emulator it gives strange verifyError and doesn't show any clue that where the error is.

my LogCat stack trace is as follows;

```
01-09 06:02:14.192: I/dalvikvm(951): Could not find method              
com.facebook.android.Facebook.getAccessToken, referenced from method    
com.socialpro.common.SocialMgtProApp.authorizeOnFacebook
01-09 06:02:14.222: W/dalvikvm(951): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 124:    
Lcom/facebook/android/Facebook;.getAccessToken ()Ljava/lang/String;
01-09 06:02:14.222: D/dalvikvm(951): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
01-09 06:02:14.254: I/dalvikvm(951): Could not find method     
com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken, referenced    
from method com.socialpro.common.SocialMgtProApp.authorizeOnLinkedin
01-09 06:02:14.254: W/dalvikvm(951): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 150:  
Lcom/google/code/linkedinapi/client/oauth/LinkedInOAuthService;.getOAuthAccessToken   



(Lcom/google/code/linkedinapi/client/oauth/LinkedInRequestToken;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/code/l    inkedinapi/client/oauth/LinkedInAccessToken;
01-09 06:02:14.282: D/dalvikvm(951): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0004
01-09 06:02:14.332: I/dalvikvm(951): Could not find method twitter4j.Twitter.getOAuthAccessToken,     
referenced from method com.socialpro.common.SocialMgtProApp.authorizeOnTwitter
01-09 06:02:14.332: W/dalvikvm(951): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 734:   
Ltwitter4j/Twitter;.getOAuthAccessToken  
(Ltwitter4j/auth/RequestToken;Ljava/lang/String;)Ltwitter4j/auth/AccessToken;
01-09 06:02:14.332: D/dalvikvm(951): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0004
01-09 06:02:14.422: I/dalvikvm(951): Could not find method   
com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken, referenced  
from method com.socialpro.common.SocialMgtProApp.beginLinkedInAuthorization
01-09 06:02:14.452: W/dalvikvm(951): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 151:   
Lcom/google/code/linkedinapi/client/oauth/LinkedInOAuthService;.getOAuthRequestToken \
(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/code/linkedinapi/client/oauth/LinkedInRequestToken;
01-09 06:02:14.452: D/dalvikvm(951): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0017
01-09 06:02:14.452: I/dalvikvm(951): Could not find method    
com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInRequestToken.getAuthorizationUrl, referenced    
from method com.socialpro.common.SocialMgtProApp.beginLinkedInAuthorization
```

Answer (score 0):

In proguard-android.txt type:

```
-dontwarn org.twitter4j.**
-dontwarn twitter4j.**
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn oauth.signpost.signature.**
-dontwarn com.android.support.**
```

I don't know all your libs, maybe you should delete the same ones from this list.

And in gradle.build:

```
compile project(':facebook'){
dependencies {
compile ('com.android.support:support-v13:+'){
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:+'){
               exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
           }
       }}
    compile ('org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:+'){
        exclude group: 'twitter4j.management'
    }
```